# How can I separate np.datetime64 information into different columns?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime64

I'm trying to create a date array whose colums are: *day*, *month* and *year* between two specific dates (time delta = 1 day). I know this must be very simple to do, but I couldn't find a similar example.

I've found that I can create date arrays using numpy datetime64 as follows:

```
import numpy as np
dates = np.arange(np.datetime64('2010-01-01'),np.datetime64('2014-12-31'))
```

Although this produces the list of dates I need, I can't find in the documentation/google how to split them into columns in a numpy array.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [25]: dates = np.arange(np.datetime64('2010-01-01'),np.datetime64('2014-12-31'))
In [26]: dates
Out[26]: 
array(['2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03', ..., '2014-12-28',
       '2014-12-29', '2014-12-30'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
In [27]: dates.shape
Out[27]: (1825,)
```

Like a regular `np.arange` (e.g. `np.arange(1825)`), this creates a 1d array spanning a range of values.  To be clear the array contains numeric values (floats) that represent the date value.  The `ndarray` code  uses the specificed `dtype` to interpret those numbers.  When displaying the array it renders the data as these data strings (as dictated by the `[D]` part of the `dtype`).

What sort of columns do you need?

As with any 1d array, you can create a volume vector with:

```
In [28]: dates[:,None]
Out[28]: 
array([['2010-01-01'],
       ['2010-01-02'],
       ['2010-01-03'],
       ..., 
       ['2014-12-28'],
       ['2014-12-29'],
       ['2014-12-30']], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

---

```
alist = dates.tolist()
In [59]: alist[:10]
Out[59]: 
[datetime.date(2010, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2010, 1, 2),
 datetime.date(2010, 1, 3),
 datetime.date(2010, 1, 4),
 datetime.date(2010, 1, 5),
 datetime.date(2010, 1, 6),
 datetime.date(2010, 1, 7),
 datetime.date(2010, 1, 8),
 datetime.date(2010, 1, 9),
 datetime.date(2010, 1, 10)]
```

produces a list of `datetime` objects.  We extract year, month, day from those objects iteratively.

```
In [66]: np.array([[x.year, x.month, x.day] for x in alist])
Out[66]: 
array([[2010,    1,    1],
       [2010,    1,    2],
       [2010,    1,    3],
       ..., 
       [2014,   12,   28],
       [2014,   12,   29],
       [2014,   12,   30]])
```

`np.datetime64` dtype doesn't have the exact equivalent.  We can convert them into various units, and take differences.

```
In [68]: yrs = dates.astype('datetime64[Y]')
In [69]: yrs
Out[69]: array(['2010', '2010', '2010', ..., '2014', '2014', '2014'], dtype='datetime64[Y]')
In [70]: mths = dates.astype('datetime64[M]')-yrs
In [71]: mths
Out[71]: array([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 11, 11, 11], dtype='timedelta64[M]')
In [72]: days = dates - dates.astype('datetime64[M]')
In [73]: days
Out[73]: array([ 0,  1,  2, ..., 27, 28, 29], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
```

With different `dtypes` we can't directly concatenate these.  But convert them to ints we can get the same 2d array:

```
In [76]: np.stack((yrs.astype(int), mths.astype(int), days.astype(int)),axis=1)
Out[76]: 
array([[40,  0,  0],
       [40,  0,  1],
       [40,  0,  2],
       ..., 
       [44, 11, 27],
       [44, 11, 28],
       [44, 11, 29]])
```

(year needs an offset).

```
In [77]: np.stack((yrs.astype(int)+1970, mths.astype(int), days.astype(int)),axis=1)
```

Or a structured array 'stacking':

```
In [78]: np.rec.fromarrays([yrs, mths, days])
Out[78]: 
rec.array([('2010',  0,  0), ('2010',  0,  1), ('2010',  0,  2), ...,
 ('2014', 11, 27), ('2014', 11, 28), ('2014', 11, 29)], 
          dtype=[('f0', '<M8[Y]'), ('f1', '<m8[M]'), ('f2', '<m8[D]')])
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for " day, month and year " columns IIUC.

Comment: That's my guess too.  But if so, it should be clearly stated in the question.

Comment: Splitting these dates isn't as trivial as it might seem.  I can't find an explicit `get_month` method or function for such a dtype.   We either have to work with a list of `datetime` objects, or play games with the `datetime64` units.

Comment: @hpaulj This is exactly what I needed. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be in a Numpy array you could use Pandas --

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DatetimeIndex
dates = DatetimeIndex(np.arange(np.datetime64('2010-01-01'),np.datetime64('2014-12-31')))

date_cols = [[d.year, d.month, d.day] for d in dates]
```

Otherwise, I would avoid numpy and do the entire thing with datetime --

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

st = datetime(2010, 1, 1) # or datetime.strptime("2010-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
ed = datetime(2014, 12, 31) # or datetime.strptime("2014-12-31", "%Y-%m-%d")

count =  ed - st
date_cols = []
for d in range(count.days+1):
    date = st + timedelta(days=d)
    date_cols.append([date.year, date.month, date.day])
print(date_cols)
```